# Proper way to create accordion control using qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create accordion qml control like [this](https://webix.com/assets/widgets/accordion/basic-accordion.png).
First I thought that I can use combobox and customize it but now I think it is impossible.
Is there any standerd control that I can use? If not can you help me with controls structure?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/RealworldSystems/qml-widgets-library/tree/master/qmltemplates/AccordionList).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/crapp/qaccordion) might also be of interest since its related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093280/how-to-create-an-animated-variable-size-accordion-component-in-qtquick-qml

Comment: I thought it might be useful to add an example i found useful to look at. In the Qt examples, there is an expanding delegates example that makes use of states. Its a nice clean way to approach the same problem though it does have the pollution of a listview implementation in addition to what you asked. I will leave it here for anyone who may be interested. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-declarative-modelviews-listview-expandingdelegates-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just playing with QML

PanelItem.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {
    default property var contentItem: null
    property string title: "panel"
    id: root
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    height: 30
    Layout.fillHeight: current
    property bool current: false
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0
        Rectangle {
            id: bar
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 30
            color:  root.current ? "#81BEF7" : "#CEECF5"
            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: root.title
            }
            Text {
                anchors{
                    right: parent.right
                    top: parent.top
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                    margins: 10
                }
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: "^"
                rotation: root.current ? "180" : 0
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                onClicked: {
                    root.current = !root.current;
                    if(root.parent.currentItem !== null)
                        root.parent.currentItem.current = false;

                    root.parent.currentItem = root;
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            anchors.top: bar.bottom
            implicitHeight: root.height - bar.height
            clip: true
            Behavior on implicitHeight {
                PropertyAnimation { duration: 100 }
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            if(root.contentItem !== null)
                root.contentItem.parent = container;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 1
        property var currentItem: null
        PanelItem {
            title: "Panel 1"
            Rectangle {
                color: "orange"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
        PanelItem {
            title: "Panel 2"
            Rectangle {
                color: "lightgreen"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
        PanelItem {
            title: "Panel 3"
            Rectangle {
                color: "lightblue"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
        PanelItem {
            title: "Panel 4"
            Rectangle {
                color: "yellow"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I guess there is some errors. This elements "horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight"  and "MouseArea {" belongs to Rectangle ar not? I have some errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! This example works great. Now I need some time to understand architecture :)

Comment: There is one mistake here: When clicking the header, to expand, then collapse and expand again, it fails. This is, as in the `onClicked`-handler, on the third click, you first correctly set the `root.current` to true. But as the new Item is also the old currentItem, you then set it again to `false`. To avoid that change the line `if(root.parent.current != null)` to `if(root.parent.current != null && root.parent.current != root)` to prevent that.

Comment: doesn't work for me. For the ```bar``` no ```container``` appears.

Answer (score 1):

What about using this open source component which I did here
[Accordion component](https://svn.gov.pt/projects/ccidadao/browser/middleware-offline/trunk/_src/eidmw/eidguiV2/components/Accordion.qml) and used here [Accordion component example](https://svn.gov.pt/projects/ccidadao/browser/middleware-offline/trunk/_src/eidmw/eidguiV2/contentPages/security/PageSecurityCertificatesForm.ui.qml).

You only need to initialize:

```
Components.Accordion {
    id: acordion
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10
}
```

And create the data dynamically like this:

```
propertyAcordion.model = [
{
    'menuTitle': value,
    'children': [
        {
            'menuTitle': value,
            'children': [
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the MouseArea click part as below with some added condition.  Thanks to folibis for this qml accordian menu.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
    onClicked: {
        root.current = !root.current;
        if(root.parent.currentItem !== null) {
            if(root.parent.currentItem !== root)
                root.parent.currentItem.current = false;
        }

        root.parent.currentItem = root;
    }
}
```